# Help in managing a iostream

Tags: c++, iostream, boost-iostreams

Suppose that I get a stringbuf with some content that include certain character sequences who must be removed:

```
std::stringbuf string_buff;
std::iostream io_stream (&string_buff);
io_stream << "part-one\r\npart-two\r\npart-three\r\nEND";
```

There, the CRLF pairs must be removed, so I've tested some as:

```
int pos = 0;
while (true) {
    pos = string_buff.str().rfind("\r\n");
    if (pos == string_buff.str().npos) {
        break;
    } else {
        std::string preamble = string_buff.str().substr(0, pos);
        std::string postamble = string_buff.str().substr(pos +2);
        io_stream.seekp(0);
        io_stream << preamble << postamble;
    }
}
```

But the sequence remains of the same length. So, I get the following result:

```
 part-onepart-twopart-threeENDNDNDND
```

I suppose that there are some way to do this -and more elegant- but I'm unable to find the way.

By the way. It seems that the direct manipulation on the inner string does not work. I say tings like:

```
 string_buff.str().clear();
```

Neither

```
 io_stream.clear();
```

or

```
 io_stream.flush();
```

> **Unfortunately I mistaken in my initial approach**

As I mentioned earlier, the real problem is related to a `boost::asio::streambuf` and my mistake was in try to mimic that, with a `std::istream` in a separate console application for test purposes.

Of course, with an asio::streambuf y can't do some as

```
 strembuf.str("");
```

So the real situation is this:

```
 boost::asio::streambuf stream_buff;
 std::iostream response_stream(&stream_buff);
 response_stream << "part-one\r\npart-two\r\npart-three\r\nEND";
```

My apologies for the confussion.

The question remains the same: How can I remove the CRLF -or any other- character sequence from the input?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Space_COwbOy as mentioned in the addendum to my original post, the question remains the same: suppress certain character sequences, but in an asio::streambuf instead of a std::stringbuf.

Answer (score 3):

You are close! The way to make the streambuf empty is

```
String_buff.str("");
```

That will assign it the empty string.

(string_buff.str().clear() just empties a **copy** of the contents :-)

Comment: indeed, replacing the io_stream.seekp(0); sentence by string_buff.str(""); the thing work. Because the real problem is related with an boost::asio::streambuf, I will check that your's solution still work int that enviroment.

Comment: I feel that you don't mess the question, and your solution is perfectly adequated in the context of my initial question. Unfortunately, as I pointed out in the addendum to my question (see above), mistaken in mimic the problem, and used an std::stringbuf in place of an asio:streambuf. Any way, the question remains.

Comment: I don't know enough about boost::asio to have an answer there. Generally it depends a lot on what is connected at the other end of the stream. Can't help you with that, sorry.

Comment: Even that kind of comment may be of interest to me. Perhaps because I've suspected some similar idea, and because as a ultimate resort, my thought is do a plain copy of the content ant treat it in a regular std::string or even in an asio:string as Rob Adams suggested. There my only concern is not bloat my code with those all librarys.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Boost.String](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/string_algo.html).

```
string s(string_buf.str());
boost::erase_all(s, "\r\n");
string_buf.str(s);
```

or, if you need the line-ends replaced with other whitespace:

```
string s(string_buf.str());
boost::replace_all(s, "\r\n", " ");
string_buf.str(s);
```

And [yes](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringbuf/str/), `stringbuf.str()` returns a *copy of*, not a *reference to* the string.

Comment: I think you nailed. Also, there actually is no question there, so did a good job of finding one to answer :)

Comment: Adams. Thanks for your advice. I must explore that library, but I think is out of the scope with my problem. Anyway I assure you that your advice will not fall on deaf ears